# How to select and get data from multiple tables (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve data from multiple rows through Laravel Eloquont:
Here is what i have tried:

```
        $currUser = Auth::User();
        ### search
        
        
        $output_product = $currUser->table('products')
            ->join('product_variants', 'products.product_id', '=', 'product_variants.product_id')
            ->join('product_images', 'product_vairants.id', '=', 'product_images.vairant_id')
            ->select('products.title', 'products.description', 'product_variants.price', 'product_variants.quantity', 'product_images.imgurl')->where('products.product_id', $product_id)
            ->get();        
        return $output_product;
                        
        }
```

But this function is not returning anything,

i am adding a query here which is working fine: 
 `$output_product = $currUser->products()->where('product_id', $product_id)->first();`

Thanks

Comment: typos in your second join (vairant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thorugh query builder you can do this like:

```
$output_product = DB::table('products')
->select('products.title', 'products.description', 'product_variants.price','product_variants.quantity', 'product_images.imgurl')
->join('product_variants', 'products.product_id', '=', 'product_variants.product_id')
->join('product_images', 'product_vairants.id', '=', 'product_images.vairant_id')
->where('products.product_id', $product_id)
->get();
return $output_product;
```

And if you want to do with Eloquont.you need to define all the relationships in the respective Model classes

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like;

DB::table('')....

make a join with user-s table and in the end and a where user id is equal to $currUser->id